# Конвертация url юникод

Tags: python, url, unicode

Как на питоне конвертировать урл такого вида:

```
xn----jtbaaldsgaoflxr4fyc.xn--p1ai/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%82%D1%8B/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8/482-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B
```

в читаемый вид:

```
https://симптомы-лечение.рф/narodnue-recepty/bolezni-krovi/482-kak-bystro-ponizit-kholesterin-narodnymi-sredstvami
```

Answer (score 1):

Для парсинга URI есть стандартная библиотека `urlparse`.
Для декодирования `Punycode` нужно вызвать `str.decode('idna')`.
Таким образом, данную строку можно декодировать так:

```
import urlparse
s = "xn----jtbaaldsgaoflxr4fyc.xn--p1ai/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%82%D1%8B/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8/482-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B"
domain = s[:s.index('/')]
path = s[s.index('/'):]
print ( domain.decode('idna')  + urlparse.unquote(path).decode('utf8'))
```